# How to android sqlite3_prepare_v2

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I porting to android platform from C sqlite3.
It is code below.

```
    final String tsql =
            "select cA, cB from tA where cC=?1 and (cD & 255)=?2 order by cD";

    Cursor dbo = DB.db().rawQuery(tsql, new String[] {String.valueOf(101), String.valueOf(102)});
    try {
        if (dbo.moveToNext()) {
            res1 = dbo.getInt(0);
            res2 = dbo.getInt(1);
        }
    } finally {
        dbo.close();
    }
```

In result, Row set was not found.

```
"select cA, cB from tA where cC=?1 and (cD & 255)=?2 order by cD";
```

Above statement is NG, But the following is OK.

```
"select cA, cB from tA where cC=?1 and (cD & 255)=102 order by cD";
```

Why did you ?
I want to do it in the way of parameter query.
What should i do?